# position fixed with width 100% didn't wrap within body?

Tags: html, css

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


#footer {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    position:fixed;
    padding:0 5px;
    margin:10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x8b4t1ce/

It flowed to the right when I use margin 10? why?

Answer (score 0):

**Now Remove** `width:100%;` and **add** to `left:0;` and `right:0;` in your `#footer`

as like this

```
#footer {
    left:0;  // add this  line
    right:0;  //  add this line
    width:100%; // remove this line
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    position:fixed;
    padding:0 5px;
    margin:10px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/x8b4t1ce/1/)**